# neural net with external nonlinear function on output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am interested in trying NN in a perhaps unusual setting.

The input to the NN is a vector.  The output is also a vector.  However, the training data and error is not computed directly on this output vector, but is a (nonlinear) function of this output vector.  So at each epoch, I need to activate the NN, find an output vector, apply this to my (external) nonlinear function to compute a new output vector.  However, this new output vector is of length 1 and the error is computed based on just this single output.

Some questions:

1. Is this something that NN might usefully do?
2. Is this a structure that is well-known already?
3. Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: I'm afraid that you're not going to get an answer (unless you add a specific use-case or a code example). The closest thing that comes to my mind is some sort of reinforcement learning (what is your non-linear function?). And I think you might have better luck on stats.stackexchange.com, as in it's current form, this question is not related to scikit-learn...

Answer (score 3):

1. In principle, yes.
2. Yes, this is what a softmax unit does. It takes the activations at the output layer and computes a single value from them, which is then used to compute the error.
3. You need to know the partial derivative of your multivariate function (let's call it *f*). From there, you can use the chain rule to compute the derivative of the error in the parameters of *f* and backpropagate the error derivative.

Comment: I think what you're arguing for is essentially incorporating the 'external' output layer into the net

Comment: @BenAllison: I'm not aware of any NN text that regards the final output as "external" to the net, but yes, I guess so.